# Why do I get null as array element?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I  have found a great [tutorial](http://www.sherif.mobi/2012/05/string-arrays-and-object-arrays-in.html) about storing arrays in SharedPreferences. Every time I add one item to an array, I store it in SharedPreferences, but when loading the array I get null for all values. Size of the array is increased by 1 every time, but the elements are stored as null. Why?

```
String tname[] = new String[loadArray(t_name, this).length + 1];
for (int i=0; i<tname.length; i++)
{
    Log.i("tname[" + i + "]", tname[i] + "");  //null
}
tname[tname.length-1] = et_name;  //this is a string which is not null
saveArray(tname, t_name, NewSchedule.this);

public boolean saveArray(String[] array, String arrayName, Context mContext) {   
        SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("sp_name", 0);  
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();  
        editor.putInt(arrayName +"_size", array.length);  
        for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)  
            editor.putString(arrayName + "_" + i, array[i]);  
        return editor.commit();  
    } 

    public String[] loadArray(String arrayName, Context mContext) {  
        SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("sp_name", 0);  
        int size = prefs.getInt(arrayName + "_size", 0);  
        String array[] = new String[size];  
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++)  
            array[i] = prefs.getString(arrayName + "_" + i, null);  
        return array;  
    }
```

Am I using the found code the right way?

****SOLUTION based ony 10s' answer:**

```
String tname[] = new String[loadArray(t_name, this).length + 1];
String[] prevPrefs = loadArray(t_name, this);
for(int i=0; i<prevPrefs.length; i++) {
   tname[i] = prevPrefs[i];  //0th element will be null, as well as e.g. the 4th when there are 3 elements
}
for (int i=0; i<tname.length; i++)
{
    if (tname[i] == null) {  //so we put the new value in place of the null
        tname[i] = et_name;
    }
}

//Arraylists are much handier than arrays
if (arr_names.size() > 0) arr_names.clear(); //first clear all elements
for (int i=0; i<tname.length; i++) {
   if (tname[i] != null) arr_names.add(tname[i]);
}
for (int i=0; i<arr_names.size(); i++) {
    if (arr_names.get(i) == null) {
        arr_names.remove(i);
        }
}

String[] tname2 = new String[arr_names.size()]; //create new array
for (int i=0; i<tname2.length; i++)  //popluate new array
{
    tname2[i] = arr_names.get(i);
}

saveArray(tname2, t_name, NewSchedule.this);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
String tname[] = new String[loadArray(t_name, this).length + 1];
```

This line does not create an array that is filled up with values: the `loadArray(t_name, this).length + 1` actually returns a number. All this is actually translated as:

```
String tname[]= new String[5];
```

which actually creates a new array of Strings that has null values.

Solution: you should then iterate among the items of a temporary `prevPrefs[]` that is loaded from the `loadArray()` method of yours and add them in the `tname[]` like this:

```
String[] prevPrefs = loadArray(t_name, this);
for(int i=0; i<prevPrefs.length; i++) {
   tname[i] = prevPrefs[i];
}
```

then you would have the array filled up with the values of the previous one and you can add to the last empty spot the new value as you already did.

Comment: How could I have forgot this?? tname[i] = t_name[i]; throws an error: The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to String

Comment: my mistake. I have guessed that tname was a `String[]`. Wait a moment.

Comment: In compilation mode. t_name[i] in underlined with red

Comment: yeap my bad. try the updated one. You can also make some modifications in the above code to make it "better". But I think you got the big picture.

Comment: You have the correct solution. I added my modified one into my question. I am sure there is an easier version but this works at last. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

this line is absolutely wrong:

```
String tname[] = new String[loadArray(t_name, this).length + 1];
```

this line says -> load the array from the preferences and right after that
allocate new memory to tname

hence you will always get null in tname members.

you should get the array size prior to the loading of the array itself from the preferences, create the array (according to the size), and only then copy the array strings from the preferences

<<<<< EDIT >>>>>>

```
    String tname[] = loadArray(t_name, this); // only load the array, don't need "new String[]"

    for (int i=0; i<tname.length; i++)
    {
        Log.i("tname[" + i + "]", tname[i] + "");  //null
    }

    tname[tname.length-1] = et_name;  //this is a string which is not null
    saveArray(tname, t_name, MainActivity.this);

  public String[] loadArray(String arrayName, Context mContext)
  {
    SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("sp_name", 0);
    int size = prefs.getInt(arrayName + "_size", 0);
    String array[] = new String[size + 1]; // +1 for storing the next value that should be saved
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        array[i] = prefs.getString(arrayName + "_" + i, null);
    return array;
  }
```

Comment: Didn't you mix t_name with tname? I save the array by the name of t_name and after loading I put all values into an array called tname. Totally different. And how am I supposed to know the number of stored values without loading the array?

Comment: Sorry, there was a problem with tname[tname.length-1] = et_name; IndexOutOfBounds